# Problem with for loops and float' object is not a iterable

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, typeerror

I was trying to solve a variance problem, but after the for loop **I can't the sum** values to finally dived by the numbers of items in the list.

```
lista = [1.86, 1.97, 2.05, 1.91, 1.80, 1.78]

n = len(lista)         #NUMBERS OF DATA IN THE LIST
MA = sum(lista)/n      #ARITHMETIC MEAN

for x in lista:
     y = pow(x - MA, 2)    #SUBTRACTION OF ALL DATA BY THE MA, RAISED TO THE POWER OF 2
     print(y)
print(sum(y)/n)       # AND THAT IS IT, I CAN'T FINISH
```

I‘m trying to do this work for days and I didn't discovery yet. Is it possible to finish or should I just quit it because there are better ways to solve it?

The result of the variance must be: 0.008891666666666652

PS: I don't want to have to install other programs or libs like pandas or numpy

Answer (score 1):

You are just updating the value of y each time you run the loop so y will be a single element after it reached end of loop.

What you are printing is :

```
sum(pow(1.78 - MA, 2)/2)
```

So either you store each value of y inside function in a array of simply do a thing

```
y=0
y = pow(x-ma, 2) 
y += y
```

Comment: You forgot the loop in the last snippet...

Answer (score 0):

I did it again and found the result, thanks Deepak Singh for your help, the asnwer is:

```
lista = [1.86, 1.97, 2.05, 1.91, 1.80, 1.78]

n = len(lista)
MA = sum(lista)/n
y = 0

for x in lista:
     subts = pow(x - MA, 2)
     y = (y + subts)

print("Varience:", y/n)
```